# Confusion regarding belong_to, has_one, has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to extend the function of a Shift model in my project.
I have two types of shifts Ashift and Bshift, that are immediately related to Shift.

My confusion stems from how to set up the associations in Shift. This is what I have:

I am trying to say that Shift has one **or the other** dependent shift class, but not both, and also not neither.

```
class Ashift < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shift
end
class Bshift < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shift
end

class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :ashift
  has_one :bshift
end
```

I am sure this is clearly laid out in the [association guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) but I've read it a couple of times, and I am still subtlety confused.

Does has_one, or has_many, refer to each instance of the model, or the Model class as a whole? Is there a different, or better way of doing this?

Comment: What are "Shifts"? Do they have a containing object, like an "Employee" or a "User"? What is an AShift, or a BShift?

Comment: Shifts have a date, start time and a name to call the shift by, and a user that works the shift. The Ashift works in one part of the department and the Bshift works in another, and the schedules are independent and not overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use has one and [STI](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance) [readmore about this here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/single-table-inheritance-vs-polymorphic-associations-in-rails-af3a07a204f2)

```
class TheShift < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shift
end

class Ashift < TheShift 
end

class Bshift < TheShift 
end

class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :theshift
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried something similar, but I didn't know about the Single-Table Inheritance, and the need for a type: column, so it didn't work. This worked well.